# Swashbuckle custom JsonSerializer settings

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

Using SwashBuckle 5.6.0 with WebAPI 5.2.3 and NewtonSoft.Json 8.0.3 I am getting errors trying to load the Swagger web page.
The problem boils down to SwaggerUI not being able to handle `null` methods in the `path` part of the `spec` object.

A simple fix would be to add

```
var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
  SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
  }
};
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
```

to Global.asax, but that would break the API to clients.
Now is there a way to change the `JsonSerializerSettings` specifically for Swagger, without changing the global settings?

Edit:

Add `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));` to Global.asax and here is the `JsonContentNegotiator` class. This will trigger the issue

```
public class JsonContentNegotiator : IContentNegotiator
{
    //http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/
    private readonly JsonMediaTypeFormatter _jsonFormatter;

    public JsonContentNegotiator(JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter)
    {
        _jsonFormatter = formatter;
    }

    public ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
    {
        return new ContentNegotiationResult(_jsonFormatter, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Fixed it by removing the JsonContentNegotiator class and instead adding:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: I don't see anything on the swaggerconfig.cs that will allow us to do that, but definitely an interesting option

Comment: I added the opposite `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include` to my api trying to break it but nothing... 
_
Can you provide a minimal project reproducing your issue?

Comment: Hi Did you find a way to set the formatter just for swagger?